# Python - установка блока на сервере minecraft (Telegram Bot)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, api, telegram, minecraft

Я бы хотел попросить помощи у вас, либо ответа в виде решения. Как вам будет удобно.
Задача следующая:
Есть сервер Minecraft 1.16.5 (условно, можно другие).
Будет telegram bot
Нужен плагин, в который бот будет отправлять:

1. id блока
2. Координату блока

Затем при помощи бота можно будет ставить блок на указанной кординате.
Как это реализовать? Плюс хорошо бы иметь пример команды из самого скрипта python
Т.е. отправка - поставка.

Comment: Слушайте, тут так дела не делаются, для начала предпримите некоторые попытки в реализации задуманного вами плагина, а затем, если что-то не получится, мы постараемся вам помочь, но обязательно отправьте ваши попытки реализации

Comment: Я пытался это реализовать +- пол года назад, но успешно забросил. Просто я думаю, что кто-то уже делал нечто похожее. Ранее пытался перевести,к примеру, звуки winsound в ноты и долго мучался. Потом оказалось, что есть решение. Наверное да, неправильно поставил вопрос. Мне бы примеры схожих кейсов.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно показать пример реализации. Иначе могу подсказать только использовать [TelegramChat](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/telegramchat.16576) в совокупности с командой [/setblock](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/setblock)